# Linq Count Returned Results

Tags: linq

```
//Feedback Check
var generalFeedbackQuery = from feedbackElements in xml.Elements("feedback")
                           select new
                           {
                               Feedback = feedbackElements.Element("general").Value,
                               PostiveFeedback = feedbackElements.Element("positive").Value,
                               NegativeFeedback = feedbackElements.Element("negative").Value
                           };

Assert.AreEqual(actual.feedback, generalFeedbackQuery.ElementAt(0).Feedback);
Assert.AreEqual(actual.positiveFeedback, generalFeedbackQuery.ElementAt(0).PostiveFeedback);
Assert.AreEqual(actual.negativeFeedback, generalFeedbackQuery.ElementAt(0).NegativeFeedback);
```

Is it possible to check whether the query returned anything?

Like

```
if(generalFeedbackQuery.Count())....
```

This seems to work, but if you add a watch on the Count it doesn't seem to exist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of seeing whether or not *anything* was returned is to use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx). That will stop and return true as soon as it gets any results, rather than looping through all of them.

(If you actually want the count, then `Count()` is indeed the right way to go. My guess is that the Watch window is confused by it being an extension method. You could explicitly call `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(generalFeedbackQuery)` which may work.)